# Camera.takePicture taking longer since XE11

Tags: camera, google-glass, google-gdk

I notice that until XE10 Camera.takePicture used to take about 800ms before invoking the JPEG callback. This has gone up to about 1.7 seconds in XE11. Is this due to any recent picture quality related enhancements and are there any options available in the Camera API to choose speed vs. quality?

Comment: I have only used XE11 with the startActivityForResult method (not Camera API) but in the example I put together it often takes about 5-10 seconds for the image to be available after returning from the camera activity. Seems like a long time. Hopefully XE12 will shed some light on this and provide a thumbnail.

Answer (score 1):

Is this delay consistently repeatable under different conditions (for example, immediately after the activity starts vs. after it's been running for a while)? If so, please file an issue on our [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list) so that we can investigate.

Comment: Yes its happening consistently and in all occasions (activity start, a while later, low cpu load etc). I've now filed a bug in issue tracker.

Comment: looks like it's in the issue tracker now: https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=269